# Limit of improper integral

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

I have a function $F(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$. If $f(x) \to L$  show that $F(x) \to L$ as $x\to\infty$.

So far i have tried to split the integral up like so
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\left(\int_0^bf(t) \, dt + \int_b^x f(t) \, dt \right)  $$
but a bit further along this I get stuck

Comment: Have you considered L'Hopital?

Comment: Do you mean on both integrals or before the split? Also I don't know if the integral is differentiable

Comment: The integral is a differentiable function of $x$ at points where $f$ is continuous.  Weaken that assumption and I think you might encounter some subtleties.  L'Hopital's rule gives an answer quickly if $f$ is everywhere continuous.  But it often gives an answer quickly without giving much insight. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I've deleted my answer; I will edit it and then restore it.

Comment: Assuming $F(x)$ is differentiable then it seams easy with L'Hopital but how do i then prove it is differentiable?

Comment: One of the fundamental theorems of calculus says that $x\mapsto\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ is differentiable at all points where $f$ is continuous.  Without the assumption of continuity, there is more work to do. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Good points. When I suggested using L'Hopital, I was probably unconsciously making assumptions about the OP's background and the probable expected response based on the wording of the problem. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, we want to show that whenever $x$ is bigger than some number $x_0$ (which depends on $\varepsilon$) the difference between $L$ and $\frac 1 x\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ is less (in absolute value) than $\varepsilon$.

We know that there exists $x_1$ such that whenever $t>x_1$ then $|f(t)-L|<\varepsilon/2$.

So look at the difference
\begin{align}
\left|\frac 1 x \int_0^x f(t)\,dt - L\right| & = \frac 1 x \left|\int_0^x (f(t)-L)\,dt \right| \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 x \int_0^{x_1} (f(t)-L)\,dt + \frac 1 x \int_{x_1}^x (f(t)-L)\,dt.
\end{align}
The first integral is $1/x$ times something not changing as $x$ changes.  Hence it approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$.  It can be made less in absolute value than $\varepsilon/2$ by making $x$ big enough.  For the second integral we have
$$
\left|\frac 1 x \int_{x_1}^x (f(t)-L)\,dt \right| \le \frac 1 x \int_{x_1}^x |f(t)-L|\,dt\le\frac 1 x\int_{x_1}^x \frac\varepsilon2\,dx \le \frac{x-x_1} x \frac\varepsilon2 \le\frac\varepsilon2.
$$